# Include класс в классе

Tags: include, php, ооп, классы

Жили были 2 класса

```
class class_1 {
    public function __construct() {
        echo '1';
    }
}

class class_2 {
    public function __construct() {
        echo '2';
    }
}

$c_1=new class_1();
$c_2=new class_2();
```

И они работали очень хорошо по отдельности

Потом решено было их переписть

```
class class_2 {
    public function __construct() {
        include 'class_1.php';
        $c_1=new class_1();
        echo '2';
    }
}

$c_2=new class_2();
```

И вроде все было нормально

Но потом появился программист который решил обойтись без инклюда и переписал буквально

```
class class_2 {
    public function __construct() {
        class class_1 {
            public function __construct() {
                echo '1';
            }
        }
        $c_1=new class_1();
        echo '2';
    }
}
$c_2=new class_2();
```

**Вопрос:**

Как интепретатор php разворачивает второй пример?

Ведь 3-й пример работать не будет если так буквально развернуть код

При include внутри класса куда происходит инклюд файла?

Comment: этот простой пример

у меня же это класс в котором происходит поиск модулей-классов по папкам, после происходит их инклюд и создание обьектов

модули в свою очередь являются классами наследуюмыми от основного класса который приинклюден все всяких классов

все это прекрасно работает, но я хочу понять КАК МЛЯтЬ оно работает

Comment: Честно, я бы за такое руки отбивал.

Используйте [автозагрузку классов][1]

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на ваш вопрос - в [офф. документации](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php):

> Когда файл включается, его код
> наследует ту же область видимости
> переменых, что и строка, на которой
> произошло включение. Все переменные,
> доступные на этой строке во включащем
> файле будут также доступны во
> включаемом файле. Однако все функции и
> классы, объявленные во включаемом
> файле, будут доступны в глобальной
> области видимости.

Answer (score 0):

наследуйте класс от класса или в другой класс передавайте инстанс первого класса